# Pop single view on each tab tap

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, popviewcontroller

I have a tab view setup as below

```
struct TabBarView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        SetListView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Set List", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
        
        AllCardsView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Card List", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
        
        OwnedView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Owned Cards", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
        
        DecksView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Decks", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }
        
        SettingsView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
            }
    }
}
```

}

Each individual view hs its own navigation view, created as such

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that on the first four tabs you can tap the tab an change back to the previous view.

I know previously you could use the popviewcontroller method but from what I can tell there's no equivalent switfui version

Comment: What is "tab the tab"? Do you want to use a `.sheet`? Your question is very confusing. Are you familiar with the basics of SwiftUI, spend a little time learning it rather than expecting UIKit equivalents

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

Comment: I want it so that when you tap the tab, it goes back to the previous view.

Comment: What do you mean by the previous view?

Comment: Each tab has a navigationview within it, I'd like to pop the current view in the current tab back to the previous one, same as if you were clicking the back button.